# What is a lagom server in lagom framework?

Tags: scala, reactive, lagom

Inside the doc, nothing is written except a line which says " A Lagom server"

[image: Official doc]

And on searching on the doc https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/Migration14.html#Akka-HTTP-as-the-default-server-engine
Found out that Akka-http as the default server engine.
Is it so?